# Problem with Beamer, phantom, and definition environment

Tags: beamer

The following code tries to put a `vphantom` around a `definition` environment in a Beamer document but it does not compile properly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 Before 
 \begin{definition}
  inside
 \end{definition}
 after
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
 Before
 \vphantom{
  \begin{definition}
   inside
  \end{definition}
 }
 after
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The two frames created during the failed compilation are

[image: good]

and

[image: bad]

What is going wrong?

Comment: I what does this have to do with mathtools?

Comment: Is `\visible<#>{\begin{definition}...\end{definition}}` and option for you? If you don't want to create overlays, why not use `vskip`?

Comment: You can't use paragraphs in `\vphantom`

Comment: @KevinC What is the difference between `\visible` and `\only`? What would the solution be using overlays? I don't want to use `\vskip` because the space I want to add depends on specific content.

Comment: @daleif Oh, I thought `\phantom` was a `mathtools` command.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: `\visible<#>{<content>}` saves the space of `<content>`; whereas `\only<#>{<content>}` doesn't save the space.

Comment: @KevinC Oh, sorry...I meant what is the difference between `\visible` and `onslide`?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: `\visible` is not affected by transparency settings, but `\onslide` (or similarly `\uncover`) is. For example, if you have set `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`, then that's going to make the content in `\onslide` (faintly) visible, but content in `\visible` will stay invisible.

Comment: @TysonWilliams nope, I think that even comes from the TeX core

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, @egreg said that the `\phantom` family of commands can't accept a paragraph.  Therefore, one way to fix the compilation error is to wrap a [`\parbox`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox) around the paragraph.  Then `\phantom` and similar commands work as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I couldn't reach any compilation success with `\phantom` & `\xxxbox{}` as I have blocks & itemizes & beamer commands (`\item<x>`) in the code I want to hide.

On problem with `\visible` is that if there are beamer commands like `\item<x>` or `\onslide<x>` inside the section you want to hide, they will be taken into consideration and you will end up with an invisible part, but that spreads on multiple overlays.

In my case the problem is I want to show the beginning of a slide, then show "stage whisper" slides, then come back where I stopped on the slide to continue.

If anyone has a solution...

For the moment, I have 2 copies of the slide in my `.tex` file, both with all the content.

- The first copy has the end parts inside an `\invisible{xxx}`, which does not show the content but creates too much overlays.
- The second, with the whole content but is `x`s in my `\onslide<x>` that are offset so that the first part of the slide is shown directly.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What you have here is a new problem, and it's not really likely to be seen here, since this question is old.  Please ask a new question, and refer to this one, being specific about why it doesn't work.